# Requesting permission for a custom account type

Tags: android

I have created a custom account type and at the very begining of my app I try to retrieve any existing accounts of that type using AccountManager.

The problem is that I don't want to bother users (above 6.0) with dialogs in the very begining.

Is it possible to do that without asking for GET_ACCOUNTS permission, since this is a custom account type? 
Is there any workarounds for it?

Thanks.

Comment: *since this is a custom account type?* does this account type is declared in the same app? if so then, you can ... if not ... then if google didn't f** up then you SHOULD NOT be able to do this...

Comment: Yes, the Custom Account Authenticator is declared in the same app. So how can I do that?
And what do you mean by "google didn't fu**up" ?

Comment: I mean if it's not working(if some how you can iterate other then your type accounts without security exception) then it is a bug ... but as you wrote, it is your own account type, so just try to not ask about permission, as on API 23 there is no need for GET_ACCOUNTS  permission for "own account type"